# Extracting a string between two characters - Matlab (regexp)

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I'm needing to extract a string of 3 numbers between a beginning character and a possibility of three different ending characters. Staring with _a and ending with either _b, _c or _d. I know how to do it with strfind but really want to know how to use regexp.

For example string could be:

> ggggga_a123_cggggg

or/

> gggggg_a345_bggggg

or/

> gggggg_a456_dggggg

How do I just extract the three numbers without knowing which ending character it will be.
Thanks

Comment: What regular expression(s) have you tried?

Comment: I just did regexp(s,'(?<=_a).*(?=b_|c_|d_)','match');
Should this work for all instances?

Comment: That's incorrect. You need this:     `regexp(s,'(?<=_a).*(?=_b|_c|_d)','match')`

Comment: Thanks that worked

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a regex like this:

```
_a(\d{3})_[bcd]
```

What this will do is match the starting `_a`, match the 3 digits in a capture group (the `()`) for extraction, then match the second underscore and one of `b`, `c`, or `d`.